# Using Grid is there a design pattern that places all child elements except the last at the top and the last child element at the bottom?

Tags: css, grid

I'm experimenting with [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) layouts but I'm having difficulty placing a series of child elements at the top of the grid and the last child element at the bottom.

- [align-self: end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) used on the last child element positions it at the bottom but it leaves boxes 2 and 3 in the middle.
- [align-content: start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) used on the parent container positions the top elements correctly except it also positions the last item at the top which won't work.

Getting this done with Flexbox is simple enough.

1. `flex-direction: column` on the parent.
2. `justify-content: space-between` on the parent.
3. Add a wrapper container around the top content.

This causes the wrapper to be positioned at the top and the bottom element to be positioned at the bottom.

Is there a simple pattern that accomplishes the same thing with Grid?  If possible I'd like to do this without adding a wrapper element.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.top_one {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top_two {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.top_three {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.bottom_copyright {
  align-self: end;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top_one">box 1</div>
  <div class="top_two">box 2</div>
  <div class="top_three">box 3</div>
  <div class="bottom_copyright">copyright</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add a blank row between them:

```css
.container {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr auto;
}

.bottom_copyright {
  grid-row: -1;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.container {
  --children-count: 4;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(var(--children-count) - 1), auto) 1fr auto;
}

.bottom_copyright {
  grid-row: -1;
}


/* Original styles */

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.top_one {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top_two {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.top_three {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.bottom_copyright {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Demo only */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top_one">box 1</div>
  <div class="top_two">box 2</div>
  <div class="top_three">box 3</div>
  <div class="bottom_copyright">copyright</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by explicitly setting the grid rows and using either `margin-top: auto` or `align-self: end` on the last item:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.top_one {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top_two {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.top_three {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.bottom_copyright {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: auto;
  /* align-self: end; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top_one">box 1</div>
  <div class="top_two">box 2</div>
  <div class="top_three">box 3</div>
  <div class="bottom_copyright">copyright</div>
</div>
```

As an aside, you don't need the extra wrapper when doing this with Flexbox. In fact, it's quite a bit simpler with Flexbox, again using `margin: auto` on the last item:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.top_one {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top_two {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.top_three {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.bottom_copyright {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top_one">box 1</div>
  <div class="top_two">box 2</div>
  <div class="top_three">box 3</div>
  <div class="bottom_copyright">copyright</div>
</div>
```